# How do I get the html on the scope within a unit test to update after a button click event changes the active html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jasmine

I currently have the following html for the table I'm testing:

```
<table id="admin-self-assessment-table" class="table">
   <tr class="admin-self-assessment-table-headers">
       <th class="admin-tile" colspan="2">Question Category</th>
       <td class="admin-button">
           <button id="add-category-button" 
                   ng-click="selfAssessUpdateCtrl.addCategory()"
                   class="fa fa-plus-circle"></button>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

Whenever the above button is clicked, the `addCategory()` method is called correctly from the test, but the html isn't properly appended.

The function:

```
    vm.addCategory = function(){
        html = (
            '<tr class="category-heading admin-self-assessment-question-category">' +
                '<td class="category-name" contenteditable="true">Category</td>' +
                '<td><button class="button-coloring category-button-add fa fa-plus-circle"></button></td>' +
                '<td><button class="button-coloring category-table-delete fa fa-times-circle"></button></td>' +
            '</tr>');
        $('#admin-self-assessment-table').append(html);
    };
```

It's working as intended on the page. The new row appears as it should on the table and behaves as expected, but the unit test fails because the html is not actually getting added within that scope.

The unit test:

```
describe('Self-Assessment Controller', function () {
    var scope, $state, ctrl, html, httpBackend, safeService;

    beforeEach(module('generic'));
    beforeEach(module('generic.reports'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, $templateCache, $controller, $compile, _$state_, _$httpBackend_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $state = _$state_;
        httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        ctrl = $controller('selfAssessUpdateCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            org: testOrganization,
            $element: html,
            safeService: safeService
        });
        scope.selfAssessUpdateCtrl = ctrl;

        html = $templateCache.get('app/components/admin/selfAssessmentUpdate/selfAssessmentUpdate.html');
        html = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);

        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should add a new category when appropriate button is clicked', function(){
        var table = html.find('#admin-self-assessment-table').find('tr');
        html.find('#add-category-button').click();
        scope.$apply();
        expect(table.length).toEqual(2);
    });
});
```

The expectation is failing with `"Expected 1 to equal 2"`

When I console.log the table variable (which should have all the trs for the table), I get:

```
LOG:{0: <tr class="admin-self-assessment-table-headers">
                    <th class="admin-tile" colspan="2">Question Category</th>
                    <td class="admin-button">
                        <button id="add-category-button" ng-click="selfAssessUpdateCtrl.addCategory()" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>, length: 1, prevObject: {0: <table id="admin-self-assessment-table" class="table">
                <tbody><tr class="admin-self-assessment-table-headers">
                    <th class="admin-tile" colspan="2">Question Category</th>
                    <td class="admin-button">
                        <button id="add-category-button" ng-click="selfAssessUpdateCtrl.addCategory()" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>, length: 1, prevObject: {0: ..., 1: ..., 2: ..., 3: ..., 4: ..., length: ...}, context: undefined, selector: '#admin-self-assessment-table'}, context: undefined, selector: '#admin-self-assessment-table tr'}
```

Which only shows the tr that is in the original html. It isn't getting my new html appended correctly within this scope. I can't figure out why. I tried doing `scope.$digest` and `scope.$apply`.

Comment: Currently, I am running a test in protractor to achieve the same result, but I would definitely want to know how to do this through unit testing if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came up with a solution, although it doesn't use jQuery. I decided, given jQuery and Angular working so poorly together for unit testing purposes, that I would use ng-repeat and ng-model instead.

It made everything a lot cleaner!
I detailed my changes below to help anyone else who has this question.

Updated html for the table I was testing:

```
<table id="admin-self-assessment-table" class="table">
    <tr class="uniqueness admin-self-assessment-table-headers">
        <th class="admin-tile" colspan="2">Question Category</th>
        <td class="admin-button">
            <button id="add-category-button" ng-click="selfAssessUpdateCtrl.addCategory('category')"
                    class="fa fa-plus-circle"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <div ng-repeat="cat in selfAssessUpdateCtrl.cat_array" id="cat.id">
        <tr class="category-heading admin-self-assessment-question-category">
            <td class="category-name" contenteditable="true" ng-model="cat.name">{{cat.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="button-coloring category-button-add fa fa-plus-circle"
                                ng-click="selfAssessUpdateCtrl.addQuestion(cat.id, 'Question')"></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="button-coloring category-table-delete fa fa-times-circle"
                                ng-click="selfAssessUpdateCtrl.deleteCategory(cat.id)"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="question in cat.questions" class="question-assessment" id="question.id">
            <td colspan="2" class="question-name" contenteditable="true" ng-model="question.name">
                        {{question.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="question-table-delete fa fa-times-circle"
                                ng-click="selfAssessUpdateCtrl.deleteQuestion(question.id, cat.id)"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

The reason the above html is so much bigger than the original is because, while I only have the same functionality, previously, I was adding new questions and categories via jquery. Now, everything is loaded from the array in the controller below.

Whenever the above "add-category" button is clicked, the `addCategory()` method is still called, but it now edits the array on the controller `vm.cat_array = []`

The function:

```
vm.addCategory = function(categoryName){
    var newCategory = {};
    newCategory.name = categoryName;
    newCategory.questions = [];

    if(vm.cat_array.length != 0){
        newCategory.id = (parseInt(vm.cat_array[vm.cat_array.length - 1].id) + 1).toString();
    }
    else{
        newCategory.id = (0).toString();
    }
    vm.cat_array.push(newCategory);
    return newCategory.id;
};
```

The page looks exactly the same, but now the html has ng-models for each level that connect to the array. The ng-repeats in the html load in data from `cat_array` dynamically.

The unit test below now passes and the test only tests the functions within the controller, not a full integration test (which I am still using protractor to test).

The unit test:

```
describe('Self-Assessment Controller', function () {
    var scope, $state, ctrl, html, httpBackend, safeService, templateCache;

    beforeEach(module('generic'));
    beforeEach(module('generic.reports'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, $templateCache, $controller, $compile, _$state_, _$httpBackend_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $state = _$state_;
        httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        templateCache = $templateCache;

        ctrl = $controller('selfAssessUpdateCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            org: testOrganization,
            safeService: safeService
        });
        scope.selfAssessUpdateCtrl = ctrl;
        ctrl.cat_array = [];

        html = $templateCache.get('app/components/admin/selfAssessmentUpdate/selfAssessmentUpdate.html');
        html = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);

        scope.$digest();
    }));

     it('should add a category from addCategory function', function(){
        var categoryId = ctrl.addCategory("category 1");
        expect(categoryId).toEqual("0");
        expect(ctrl.cat_array.length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

Note: the test now only has to make sure that the array was appropriately updated. Since the array's length is 1, we can be sure that the `addCategory` function did add another category to the array, thus it will be loaded on the page with the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
('<tr class="category-heading admin-self-assessment-question-category">' +
'<td class="category-name" contenteditable="true">Category</td>' +
'<td><button class="button-coloring category-button-add fa fa-plus-circle"></button></td>' +
'<td><button class="button-coloring category-table-delete fa fa-times-circle"></button></td>' +
'</tr>').appendTo( $('#admin-self-assessment-table') );
```

appendTo is slightly different than append(). Also, you didn't have the `('<tr ...' )` as `$('<tr ... ')`, so it wasn't a jQuery object. Following [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) more closely you would use jQuery objects `$()` in conjuction with .append() and .appendTo(). To access the jQuery functions, you need to invoke them from jQuery objects (that's due to object oriented nature of the jquery library). Also, it is not a best practice to use both angular and jquery, but it can sometimes work.

Comment: This is returning the same error, although it does work visually and make more sense this way.  The test still fails the exact same way. (You forgot to put a $ in front of your code block there). The original reason for using them together was an unwillingness to create a factory directive for such a tiny block of code.